# C++ pointers and arithmetics

Tags: c++, pointers, math

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int *aptr;
    aptr = &a[0];
    a[2] = a[2] + 3;
    a[3] = a[5] + a[4];
    aptr++;
    (*aptr)--;
    (*(++aptr))++;
    cout << a[1] << a[2] << a[3] << a[4] << *aptr << endl;
}
```

The problem at hand is that assuming the above code compiles, I'm supposed to get an output of 06946. Can anyone sort of go through the code for me? I don't quite understand how the code arrives at the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};    
    // a is an array of 10 ints.
    int *aptr;
    // aptr is a pointer to int.
    aptr = &a[0];
    // aptr points to the 1st element of a array. i.e. a[0]
    a[2] = a[2] + 3;
    // You add 3 to a[2], i.e. third element of array to get '5' and put it back in a[2].
    // So 'a' will be {0,1,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    a[3] = a[5] + a[4];
    // You take 6th and 5th elements, add them and put it in 4th element.
    // So 'a' will be {0,1,5,9,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    aptr++;
    // aptr pointer is incremented so now it points to 2nd element of a array i.e a[1].
    (*aptr)--;
    // aptr pointer is first dereferenced to get a[1], which is then decremented.
    // So 'a' will be {0,0,5,9,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    (*(++aptr))++;
    // aptr pointer is incremented first so now it points to 3rd element i.e. a[2].
    // aptr pointer is then dereferenced to get a[2], which is then incremented.
    // So 'a' will be {0,0,6,9,4,5,6,7,8,9} and aptr points to a[2]
    cout << a[1] << a[2] << a[3] << a[4] << *aptr << endl;
   // So it should print 06946
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over each step in the code:

```
int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; //initial state of your array
int *aptr;
aptr = &a[0]; //pointer on the first element
a[2] = a[2] + 3; //a[2]=5 now
a[3] = a[5] + a[4]; //a[3]=9 now
aptr++; //pointer on the second element
(*aptr)--; //decrement the value pointed by the pointer: a[1]=0 now
(*(++aptr))++; 
//first increment the pointer the increments the value pointed by the new pointer so a[2]=6 now
```

Note that the last line might have a different behavior since it contains a postfix and prefix incrementation but since they are on two different values it should be safe.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int *aptr;
aptr = &a[0];
```

`aptr` is referencing `a[0]`

```
a[2] = a[2] + 3;
//  a[2] == 5
a[3] = a[5] + a[4];
// a[3] == 9
aptr++;
```

moving `aptr`'s reference to `a[1]`

```
(*aptr)--;
```

The * before `aptr` now means you are modifying whatever it is referencing to's VALUE. So `aptr` is POINTING to `a[1]`, and we will decrease its VALUE by 1.  Therefore `a[1]` equals to 0.

```
(*(++aptr))++;
```

Lets break this down. `(++aptr)`  means lets move the pointer from `a[1]` to `a[2]`.  `(*(++aptr))` now says lets focus on `aptr`'s VALUE. We know now `a[2] == 5`.  Finally `(*(++aptr))++` says lets increment that value by 1.  So `a[2] == 6`.  Keep in mind `*aptr` NOW also equals 6 as a result of this.

```
cout << a[1] << a[2] << a[3] << a[4] << *aptr << endl;
```

So we established that `a[1]`'s value has been changed to 0.
We determined why `a[2] == 6`, `a[3]` is `9` because of simple math
and finally `*aptr == 6` because that is the final operation we performed on our pointer.

I do hope this will help you make sense of your exercise.